# Create a new object with unique keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking to create a new object, with unique keys made of coma separated ids.
For example, i have

```
const d = {
    "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10": [
      "created_by",
      "modified_on",
      "external_organization_name",
      "Something new",
      "&excited",
    ],
    "11,1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10": [
      "created_by",
      "modified_on",
      "external_organization_name",
      "New column",
    ],
    "5,6,8": [
      "created_by",
      "modified_on",
      "external_organization_name",
      "Get new column",
    ],
  };
```

Required output:

```
{
    "1,2,3,9,10": [
      "created_by",
      "modified_on",
      "external_organization_name",
      "Something new",
      "&excited",
      "New column",
    ],
    "4, 7": [
      "created_by",
      "modified_on",
      "external_organization_name",
      "Something new",
      "&excited",
    ],
    "11": [
      "created_by",
      "modified_on",
      "external_organization_name",
      "New column",
    ],
    "5,6,8": [
      "created_by",
      "modified_on",
      "external_organization_name",
      "Something new",
      "&excited",
      "New column",
      "Get new column",
    ],
   }
```

Where right side values are merged according to left side keys,
Left side keys are comma separated ids, if any ids is common between two keys, then their right side values will be merged and create a separate key if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a number which bits represents the values and take a transformation to get the wanted gouping.

```js
const
    data = { "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10": ["created_by", "modified_on", "external_organization_name", "Something new", "&excited"], "11,1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10": ["created_by", "modified_on", "external_organization_name", "New column"], "5,6,8": ["created_by", "modified_on", "external_organization_name", "Get new column"] },
    items = [],
    temp = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((r, [a, b]) => {
            a.split(',').forEach(k => b.forEach(v => {
                if (!items.includes(v)) items.push(v);
                r[k] ??= 0;
                r[k] |= 1 << items.indexOf(v);
            }));
            return r;
        }, {}),
    groups = Object
        .entries(temp)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
            (r[v] ??= []).push(k);
            return r;
        }, {}),
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(groups)
        .map(([k, v]) => [v, items.filter((_, i) => 1 << i & k)])
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```